# How do I make for Google search to show a map on search results?

Tags: html, google-maps, dictionary, web

What I mean is, how can I make it so that, when people search for my website, a map shows? So for example, someone in Google searches for "My Company" for example, how can I make it so that, in the results, it shows a map of "My Company"? So you can see what I mean, try Googling "Mcdonald" and you will see there is a map shown in the results. Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your company [here](https://www.google.com/business/).
After that Google will automatically add the map on the right side if someone is searching for your company.

Comment: Thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for!